# Calculating probability of dependent inequalities

Tags: probability-theory

I think this has already been asked, however, I cannot find a fitting answer so I'll try it here:

Let $(X_1,X_2)\sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$. With $\mu = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
2
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix}
3 & -1\\
-1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$. I need to compute the probability that $X_1 + X_2 < 2$ and $X_1 - X_2 > 0$. If we set $Z = X_1 + X_2 - 2$ and $W = X_1 - X_2$ I can compute the probability of them separately. However, since they are not independent, the probability of both happening is different than the multiple of the probabilities.

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2690544/probability-with-covariance-matrix-3-variables) question, I did find a relatable question, however, I am not supposed to find $f(x)$ and then integrate. Can somebody tell me how to compute this probability in another way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should $a=2$ and $b\geq4$ so that $\Sigma$ is a var-cov martix?

Comment: Yes my apologies, I got confused with the correct cov. matrix but it should be correct now.

Comment: Draw a picture of the imequalities, and integrate over the region in the plane

Answer (score 1):

In this case we're lucky: Cov($X_1+X_2,X_1-X_2)=0$. This means that $\mathbb{P}(X_1+X_2<2 , X_1-X_2>0) = \mathbb{P}(X_1+X_2<2)\cdot\mathbb{P}(X_1-X_2>0)$.

From this point on it is a matter of computing the separate probabilities.